# implementing cron tasks with Java, without new VM each time

Tags: java, command-line, cron, virtual-machine

I have a bunch of different batch processes I want to run through CRON/command line.

I do not wish to create a new VM each time a task is initiated. so I gues putting in the CRONTAB `...... java something` for each task does not make sense.

How do I make it happen efficiently?

Read one suggestion about using tomcat as the container for all my tasks, is it a good idea? Some tasks take seconds, some can take two hours.

Answer (score 0):

personally, I would use a proper java scheduler (http://quartz-scheduler.org/), or something like cron4j (http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/)